# possible to create custom scrollbar graphics without flash?

Tags: html, navbar

A friend is wanting me to help her convert her flash based website to html.  She has an embedded textbox with a scrollbar that is using a flower instead of a normal scrollbar.

Avoiding the obvious question of why a user would want a non-standard element to do this task, is it possible to do this without flash?

Comment: no I can't-it's a private website and I can't share it at the moment.  Do you need a better explanation of what I'm needing?

Comment: yes, it would help to know at least how this flower is supposed to work.

Comment: Instead of the thing in the scrollbar that you move with the mouse, it's a flower, and the actual scrollbar is just a line.  So picture a vertical line with a flower that is moved up and down the line...

Answer (score 1):

http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/jScrollPane/jScrollPane.html

Answer (score 0):

If you mean TEXTAREA html form element, you can use this script http://studio.radube.com/html-textarea-custom-scrollbar . You can customize it with pure css and your own images.